# GetConfig not working for Microsoft Graph

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api

Developing APIs that consumes Microsoft Graph SDK to get list of Teams for a tenant. The code below works:
`

```
_clientSecretCredential = new ClientSecretCredential("TenantId", "ClisntId", "Secreat");
_appClient = new GraphServiceClient(_clientSecretCredential,
// Use the default scope, which will request the scopes
// configured on the app registration
new[] { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" });
            TeamCollectionResponse _rsp = new TeamCollectionResponse();

            return await _appClient.Teams.GetAsync();
```

This returns all the fields of Teams.
However, when I try to use config to get only selected fields the Graph is giving ODATA error, here is the code:

```
_clientSecretCredential = new ClientSecretCredential("TenantId", "ClisntId", "Secreat");
_appClient = new GraphServiceClient(_clientSecretCredential,
// Use the default scope, which will request the scopes
// configured on the app registration
new[] { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" });
            TeamCollectionResponse _rsp = new TeamCollectionResponse();

            return await _appClient.Teams.GetAsync((config) =>
            {
                // Only request specific properties
                config.QueryParameters.Select = new[] { "displayName", "id" };
                // Get at most 25 results
                config.QueryParameters.Top = 2;
                // Sort by display name
                config.QueryParameters.Orderby = new[] { "displayName" };
            });
```

This is from: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/teams-list?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http

I tried other fields but nothing worked.

Error:
Microsoft.Graph.Models.ODataErrors.ODataError: Exception of type 'Microsoft.Graph.Models.ODataErrors.ODataError' was thrown.
at Microsoft.Kiota.Http.HttpClientLibrary.HttpClientRequestAdapter.ThrowIfFailedResponse(HttpResponseMessage response, Dictionary`2 errorMapping, Activity activityForAttributes) at Microsoft.Kiota.Http.HttpClientLibrary.HttpClientRequestAdapter.SendAsync[ModelType](RequestInformation requestInfo, ParsableFactory`1 factory, Dictionary`2 errorMapping, CancellationToken cancellationToken) at Microsoft.Kiota.Http.HttpClientLibrary.HttpClientRequestAdapter.SendAsync[ModelType](RequestInformation requestInfo, ParsableFactory`1 factory, Dictionary`2 errorMapping, CancellationToken cancellationToken) at Microsoft.Graph.Teams.TeamsRequestBuilder.GetAsync(Action`1 requestConfiguration, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at SmartUCC.API.Controllers.TeamsController.GetAllTeams(String tenantId) in C:\Users\rupena\Documents\VerizonTeams\API\SmartUCC.API\SmartUCC.API\SmartUCC.API\Controllers\TeamsController.cs:line 80
at lambda_method6(Closure, Object)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ActionMethodExecutor.AwaitableObjectResultExecutor.Execute(ActionContext actionContext, IActionResultTypeMapper mapper, ObjectMethodExecutor executor, Object controller, Object[] arguments)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.g__Awaited|12_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, ValueTask`1 actionResultValueTask)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.g__Awaited|10_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Rethrow(ActionExecutedContextSealed context)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that the endpoint doesn't support `$orderby` [query parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/teams-list?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#optional-query-parameters). When using `$orderby` the Graph API returns the following error

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/teams?$select=id,displayName&$top=25&$orderby=displayName

{
    "error": {
        "code": "",
        "message": "The query specified in the URI is not valid. Query option 'OrderBy' is not allowed. To allow it, set the 'AllowedQueryOptions' property on EnableQueryAttribute or QueryValidationSettings.",
        "details": [],
        "innerError": {
            "message": "Query option 'OrderBy' is not allowed. To allow it, set the 'AllowedQueryOptions' property on EnableQueryAttribute or QueryValidationSettings.",
            "date": "2023-08-31T05:38:19",
            "request-id": "6e1bade7-3dd5-4e80-871f-8adbb4251880",
            "client-request-id": "c1d26c63-3c26-99d2-bc4f-a6e59a9325e7"
        }
    }
}
```

So, get rid of `OrderBy` from your code

```
_clientSecretCredential = new ClientSecretCredential("TenantId", "ClisntId", "Secreat");
_appClient = new GraphServiceClient(_clientSecretCredential,
// Use the default scope, which will request the scopes
// configured on the app registration
new[] { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" });
        TeamCollectionResponse _rsp = new TeamCollectionResponse();

        return await _appClient.Teams.GetAsync((config) =>
        {
            // Only request specific properties
            config.QueryParameters.Select = new[] { "displayName", "id" };
            // Get at most 25 results
            config.QueryParameters.Top = 2;
        });
```

Comment: That worked, any online reference? this is because I am just starting and may encounter such hidden issues. Thank you.

Comment: Also, I am not seeing the exception you posted here, is it from the online graph client?

Comment: @TechTurtle The exception in hidden inside ODataError. Check the [doc](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet/blob/dev/docs/errors.md) how to get error code and error message.

Comment: Great, so we can't fix it? or requires extra configuration?

Comment: any idea on this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77084567/groupsgroupid-members-is-not-returning-all-the-details-of-the-members