# Groups["groupid"].Members is not returning all the details of the members

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

As per online documentation available [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/group-list-members?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=csharp) the call for Groups[groupId].Members isn't returning selected user details (e.g. displayName, givenName etc. The response brings accurate items (if a group have 2 members then it will return two object) however, it just returns their IDs, while keeping other details hidden.

To Reproduce (Assuming app registration part and permission setup is done)
Create team and assign a member
Use Groups[groupId].Members.GetAsync to fetch all the details of members.

Here is the snippet:

```
                _clientSecretCredential = new ClientSecretCredential(tenantId, Helper.Tenant.Get(tenantId).ClientID, Helper.Tenant.Get(tenantId).ClientSecret);

                _appClient = new GraphServiceClient(_clientSecretCredential,
                        // Use the default scope, which will request the scopes
                        // configured on the app registration
                        new[] { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" });


                return await _appClient.Groups[groupId].Members.GetAsync();
```

Here is the output:
[image]

I tried selecting exclusively:

```
                return await _appClient.Groups[groupId].Members.GetAsync((requestConfiguration) =>
                {
                    
                    requestConfiguration.QueryParameters.Select = new string[] { "id","displayName" };

                });
```

See https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer for all the properties of member object.

I also verified permissions:
[image]

Comment: Tried to reproduce the issue but it returned user displayName. Which version of SDK do you use? Any difference if you call await _appClient.Groups[groupId].Members.GraphUser.GetAsync();

Comment: I am using version 5.24.0 and your snippet worked like a charm!! Thank you. Just curious how did you figured as I am unable to find any documentation on it.

Comment: Remember it from the [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/group-list-members?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=csharp#optional-query-parameters) that you can cast members to a specific type (group,user,application,etc.) and C# example is [here](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet/blob/dev/docs/upgrade-to-v5.md#support-for-odata-casts-in-request-builders)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably bug in SDK version 5.24. As a workaround you can directly cast users on the server side

```
return await _appClient.Groups[groupId].Members.GraphUser.GetAsync();
```

Resource:

[OData casting](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet/blob/dev/docs/upgrade-to-v5.md#support-for-odata-casts-in-request-builders)